# Windows won't boot after adding new hard drives

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive, sata

I took two WD external drives, took them apart, and installed them inside my PC. They are attached with sata to a pci expansion card with sata ports.

When they are connected the PC freezes at the "starting Windows" screen.

If I unplug them Windows boots without any problems.

The pci card supports hot swapping, so what I've tried doing is waiting for Windows to boot. Once I'm logged in, I've plugged in the hard drives and everything works. This allowed me to format the drives with NTFS. Everything seemed good.

However upon restarting my computer, it still freezes on the "starting windows" screen.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen if only one drive is connected, or only when both are?

Comment: I've tried connecting just one drive, and the problem still persists.

Comment: I would try a different expansion card.

Comment: What is the make and model of the expansion card? Have you checked for updated drivers/firmware for it? Otherwise I would agree with @Moab - I'd suspect this is your problem.

Comment: Are you able to boot to a Live CD to see if they work that way? Or do you have the ability to connect the drives to another PC to see if the problem follows them? This could help you troubleshoot if the problem is the card or the drives.

Comment: Also try moving the expansion card to a different slot if there is one available, I had this issue with old Promise cards and Windows XP, if I put it in the pci slot next to the agp slot it would not boot.

Comment: The model number of the pci card is si-pex40064.

I connected one of the hard-drives to that motherboard sata port my disk drive is on, and it booted up fine. I then connected the disk drive to the pci sata drive and it also booted up fine.

So it seems that the problem only persists when the HD is connected to the pci card. So the problem must be the pci card.